# Error when generating wordnet db file

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl, summarization

To execute `pyrouge` I should generate `wordnet db` file (on windows) by running this command:

```
cd pyrouge-master\tools\ROUGE-1.5.5\data
perl WordNet-2.0-Exceptions/buildExeptionDB.pl ./WordNet-2.0-Exceptions ./smart_common_words.txt ./WordNet-2.0.exc.db
```

But I got this error:

```
Can't locate DB_File.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DB_File module) (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at WordNet-2.0-Exceptions/build
ExeptionDB.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at WordNet-2.0-Exceptions/buildExeptionDB.pl l
ine 2.
```

So I tried to install DB_File using CPAN `cpan -i DB_File`, but i got this error

```
version.c:30:16: fatal error: db.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'version.o'
  PMQS/DB_File-1.841.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
```

Comment: How about you install `DB_File` module like it suggests? Use `cpan DB_File`.

Comment: Presumably you mean *"db file"*? I don't know what a bd file might be.

Comment: @Borodin I get this error when excuting cpan DB_File `dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'version.o'
  PMQS/DB_File-1.841.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK` (I am not a perl programmer)

Comment: Please put the complete build log in your question.

Comment: On Linux, building `DB_File` via `cpan` requires the development headers for `libdb` be installed (on Fedora that's the `libdb-devel` rpm), otherwise the build attempt will fail with exactly the same error. I don't know if the Berkeley DB library (`libdb`) exists for Windows — I assume it does — but it's a requirement for building `DB_File`.

Comment: It would appear that ActiveState's build server [is having the same issue](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x64/5.24/2400/P/PM/PMQS/BerkeleyDB-0.55.d/log-20160618T131615.txt) building `BerkeleyDB` under Windows, so that's a bad sign. (`DB_File` appears to be administratively disabled on their build servers, for some reason. But `BerkeleyDB` has the same `libdb` dependency.)